# What is the best (and most cost effective way) to run automated server operations on a certain day or time by it self?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, bigdata, analytics

I am using a load balancer (and server) to start other servers to run large database updates and analytics, etc. I am paying quite a bit for running servers. I assumed this enterprise solution would cost quite a bit but I think I might be doing things a little differently than "the norm". Any recommendations on how the "run automated function"? Any language is fine, but preferably PHP, Java, Ruby, or Python if possible. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: you should specify more details.

Comment: What's wrong with a cron job?  You can script all of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bascially run the smallest server you can and use crontab which is usually fine.
you can see more options at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171211/execute-code-every-hour